Ag-grid how to dowload csv include total when set groupIncludeTotalFooter = true
i am using ag-grid and enable group with groupIncludeTotalFooter = {true}
however when i download the total is not in the csv file
how to download csv include groupIncludeTotalFooter data?
i am using ag-grid version as below
"ag-grid-community": "^21.2.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.2.1",
"ag-grid-react": "^21.2.1",
